# jQuery code doesn't work right

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

```
$(function () {

  var width = 720;
  var animationSpeed = 1000;
  var imgTime = 3000;
  var currentSlide = 1;

  var $slideCont = $('.slide-container');
  var $slides = $slideCont.find('.slides');
  var $slide = $slides.find('.slide');

  var interval;

  function startSlider() {
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      $slides.animate({marginLeft: '-='+width}, animationSpeed, function() {
      currentSlide++;
        if (currentSlide === $slide.length) {
          currentSlide = 1;
          $slides.css({marginLeft: 0});
        };
      });
    },imgTime);
  };

  function stopSlider() {
    clearInterval(interval);
  };

  $slideCont.on('mouseenter', stopSlider).on('mouseleave', startSlider);
});
```

The slide show, the animation is absolutely working, it's okay. 
But I want, if my cursor is on a pic, the animation be paused and when my coursor leaves it resumes.
It's almost working... but it don't start when I refresh the page (just when I mouseenter to the pic and I leave it), and it doesn't pause when my cursor is on.

Thank you for all your help!!!

Comment: The var in front of the interval in the first line of the startSlider function is redeclaring it locally. Since you're declaring it outside the function just remove that 'var' and you should be goos

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just call startSlider somewhere, like this:

```
$(function () {

  var width = 720;
  var animationSpeed = 1000;
  var imgTime = 3000;
  var currentSlide = 1;

  var $slideCont = $('.slide-container');
  var $slides = $slideCont.find('.slides');
  var $slide = $slides.find('.slide');

  var interval;

  function startSlider() {
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      $slides.animate({marginLeft: '-='+width}, animationSpeed, function() {
      currentSlide++;
        if (currentSlide === $slide.length) {
          currentSlide = 1;
          $slides.css({marginLeft: 0});
        };
      });
    },imgTime);
  };

  function stopSlider() {
    clearInterval(interval);
  };

  $slideCont.on('mouseenter', stopSlider).on('mouseleave', startSlider);
   startSlider();
});
```

Comment: `startSlider` is being called on the `mouseleave` event for `$slideCont`.

Comment: Yeah, but only on the mouseleave event. Not when the page loads. That was the question, wasn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Call `startSlider()` on your Javascript. The function does not start until mouseleave is detected on the element, that's why your slideshow won't start on page load.

As for it not stopping on mouseover.   You are creating a new `interval` variable in the `startSlider()` function instead of utilizing the `interval` you have on the top.

Modify it like this and it should work.

```
 function startSlider() {
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      $slides.animate({marginLeft: '-='+width}, animationSpeed, function() {
      currentSlide++;
        if (currentSlide === $slide.length) {
          currentSlide = 1;
          $slides.css({marginLeft: 0});
        };
      });
    },imgTime);
  };'
```